# Ask for help displaying the file name on the Scandir Php list

Tags: php

My problem is showing the name of the list file in scandir.

The following is the Scandir code that I got from Google that I use, but there is no name for the file.

```
<?php

echo scanDirectoryImages("upload/portofolio/logotype");

/**
* Recursively search through directory for images and display them
* 
* @param  array  $exts
* @param  string $directory
* @return string
*/
function scanDirectoryImages($directory, array $exts = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'))

{
if (substr($directory, -1) == '/') {
    $directory = substr($directory, 0, -1);
}
$html = '';
if (
    is_readable($directory)
    && (file_exists($directory) || is_dir($directory))
) {
    $directoryList = opendir($directory);
    while($file = readdir($directoryList)) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
            $path = $directory . '/' . $file;
            if (is_readable($path)) {
                if (is_dir($path)) {
                    return scanDirectoryImages($path, $exts);
                }
                if (
                    is_file($path)
                    && in_array(end(explode('.', end(explode('/', $path)))),   $exts)
                ) {
                    $html .= '<div _ngcontent-ebu-c68="" class="col-lg-3 mb-4" id="portofolio">
                    <a _ngcontent-ebu-c68="" routerlink="" class="bg-white d-block rounded-lg lift lift-lg" href="#portofolio">
                    <img _ngcontent-ebu-c68="" src="' . $path . '" class="img-fluid rounded-lg"></a>
                    <br>
                    </div>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($directoryList);
}
return $html;
}
?>
```

Comment: The function verifies that the directory is valid, then if it is, scans it.  Are you certain the directory you specified (`upload/portofolio/logotype`) exists?  The user that runs your PHP has proper rights to read it?  Try with the absolute path (the complete path from `/`).  What debug have you tried?  Add print statements all over the code and follow it's execution.  It must reach some condition you do not expect and exit without doing the scan.  Like what I have listed above for example.

Comment: There are a log of `if` statements without `else` clauses.  When an `if` fails, nothing is written anywhere.  Add `else` clauses with a message to logs so you know which condition failed.